# Creating a Multimap from an Iterable and values function

Tags: java, guava

In Guava, is there a way to create a `Multimap` from an `Iterable` of keys and a `Function` that returns the values for that key? I'm looking for something with this signature (plus some super/extends in the generics):

```
<E, T> Multimap<E, T> create(final Iterable<E> inKeys, 
                             final Function<E, Iterable<T>> inValuesFunction);
```

I've come up with my own implementation, which wasn't too hard, but it seems like there should already be something like this in Guava. Here's my implementation:

```
<E, T> Multimap<E, T> create(final Iterable<E> inKeys, final Function<E, Iterable<T>> inValuesFunction) {
    ImmutableMultimap.Builder<E, T> builder = ImmutableMultimap.builder();
    for (E key : inKeys) {
        Iterable<T> values = inValuesFunction.apply(key);
        builder.putAll(key, values);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

It looks like it might be possible with something like this:

```
Multimaps.newListMultimap(FluentIterable.from(inKeys)
                                        .toMap(valuesFunction),
          new Supplier<List<T>>() {
            @Override
            public List<T> get() {
                return new ArrayList<T>();
            }
        });
```

but that seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: `Multimaps.newListMultimap` won't let you pass in a nonempty map.  Your implementation looks like the right way to do this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you think that method would have a chance of getting integrated into Guava? It seems reasonably generic and useful. That's my completely non-biased opinion. :-)

Comment: I have mixed feelings about it, to be perfectly honest.  In the past there's been resistance to Map-to-Multimap conversions, and this feels kind of similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you make your comment an answer, I'll toss some rep your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multimaps.newListMultimap won't let you pass in a nonempty map. Your implementation looks like the right way to do this.

If you like, file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list).